# Django Annotations affecting eachother (Max / Count)

Tags: python, django

I observed weird behavior using Django annotation in a Query set.

As long as I only count the number of child objects, everything is fine:

```
>>> myqs = Parent.objects.all().annotate(num_children=Count('children))
>>> myqs.first().num_children
4
```

When I add a second annotation regarding some child attributes using Max the counted number seems to change. Apparently, this has to do with the number of status

```
>>> myqs = Parent.objects.all().annotate(num_children=Count('children)).annotate(status=Max('children__status__color'))

>>> myqs.first().num_children
8
```

What is going on here? How do I get the expected behavior (result = 4)?

**Edit** adding Count(, **distinct=True**) solves the issue, but in my opintion those values should be distinct in the first place.

Comment: Use a subquery.

Comment: That is a workaround (like my own solution). But to my mind that issue shouldn't arise in the first place.

Comment: This is not really an issue. `__` leads to joins. Joining to multiple matching rows "duplicates" source rows.

Comment: thank you, I must have missed that